# Get Sourcecode out of website and display only a specific div tag in a WebView (AsyncTasks, Filtering, ..)

Tags: android, html, filter, android-asynctask

So I'm having issues with that code, it somehow doesn't work. I think I need a AsyncTask or something..
So, this class should get the whole HTML File of the url, and save it in a String. Then it should filter out everything except the code between  the content , so I can load it into a WebView with transparent Background later on. I do this, so the table looks like it isn't from the website but an own table from the app ^^

Here's the Activity

```
package com.mrousavy.gemeindemuckendorfwipfing;

public class EcoActivity {


public void contructor() {
    final String url = "http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/25-0-Wirtschaft+und+Gastronomie.html";
    WebView wve;


    //final String url = "http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/25-0-Wirtschaft+und+Gastronomie.html";
    String htmlString = Utils.getHTML(url);   //Throws IOException, so I chose the other way
    //CASE 1: if you have to download the html
    //String url = "http://www.muckendorf-wipfing.at/25-0-Wirtschaft+und+Gastronomie.html";
    //Retrieve html of "url" via GET
    //Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url).method(Connection.Method.GET).execute();
    //Parse html
    //Document doc = response.parse();


//CASE 2: If you already have the html in a String called htmlString
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlString);

//Select the div with id="content", where both tables are stored
    Element contentDiv = doc.select("div#content").first();
//Create a list for the data
    List<Table> tables;
//Loop on h3 titles and get the coupled table below
}
    for (Element h3 : contentDiv.select("h3")) {
        //get the text inside <h3> tag
        String h3Text = h3.text();
        //jsoup select statement to get the table
        //immediately after the <h3></h3>
        String select = "h3:contains(" + h3Text + ") ~ table";
        //Actually get the jsoup table element jTable
        Element jTable = contentDiv.select(select).first();
        //Load the data on the list
        tables.add(new Table(h3Text, jTable));
    }

//print them
public void print() {
    for (Table t : tables)
        System.out.println(t);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Here's Utils.getHTML

```
public static String getHTML(String url) throws Exception {
    try {
        URL u = new URL(url);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(u.openStream()));
        String tmp, html = "";
        while ((tmp = in.readLine()) != null) {
            html += tmp;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(10);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
        return html;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Here's Table class

```
package com.mrousavy.gemeindemuckendorfwipfing;

class Table{
String     h3Title;
String     htmlTable;
String[][] splittedTable;

Table(String h3Title, Element jTable)
{
    this.h3Title       = h3Title;
    this.htmlTable     = jTable.html();
    this.splittedTable = getSplittedTable(jTable);
}

String[][] getSplittedTable(Element jTable)
{
    //Get all the rows of the jTable
    Elements trs      = jTable.select("tr");
    //Get the number of rows
    int rows          = trs.size();
    //Get the columns of the first row (the same of all the rows)
    int columns       = trs.first().select("td").size();
    //Allocate new bidimensional array table
    String[][] table = new String[rows][columns];
    int i = 0; int j = 0;
    for ( Element tr : trs ) {
        for ( Element td : tr.select("td") ) {
            table[i][j++] = td.text();
        }
        j = 0; //reset column cursor
        i++;   //increment row cursor
    }
    return table;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String ln        = System.lineSeparator();

    sb.append(h3Title + ln);
    sb.append("--" + ln);
    sb.append(this.htmlTable + ln);
    sb.append("--" + ln);
    for (int i = 0; i < splittedTable.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < splittedTable[i].length; j++) {
            sb.append(splittedTable[i][j] + " | ");
        }
        sb.append(ln + "--" + ln);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
}
```

And here's a Try of an AsyncTask

```
AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> task = new AsyncTask() {
protected String doInBackground(Void... args) {
return Utils.getHTML(url);
}
}
String htmlString = task.execute();
```

So what can I do to get it to do exactly what I want it to do? (I wrote at the top what I want it to do)
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of AsyncTask. You can check [THIS](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-basic-jsoup-tutorial/) link and pick up some hint. You are on right course!

```
// Title AsyncTask


private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


String title;




@Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android Basic JSoup Tutorial");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }




@Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                // Get the html document title
                title = document.title();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }




@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set title into TextView
            TextView txttitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titletxt);
            txttitle.setText(title);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer! Although, I still have questions; onPostExecute Should be the current class (First code I posted) and do in Background the getHTML? And also, I still have the problem I can't filter out everything except content between <div id=content>...